# Assign to entity field count from another table JPA

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot, HSQLDB and Data JPA. I have two entities: Book(int id, String name, long votesCount) and Vote(int id, int book_id) I need to get all entries from books table into List<Book> and fill votesCount field with amount of rows in votes table with same desired book_id.

So, for given tables
books:
id name
1  book1
2  book2

votes:
id book_id
1  1
2  1
3  2

result List should contain 2 instance of Book:
name: book1, votesCount: 2
name: book2, votesCount: 1

What is the best way to do this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
class Book{

  @Id
  int id;
  String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "book")
  List<Vote> votes;

  @Transient
  long voteCount;
}
```

/////////////////////////////////

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "votes")
class Vote{
  @Id
  int id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_book_id"))
  Book book;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use computed field votesCount with @Formula;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
class Book{

  @Id
  int id;
  String name;
  
  @Formula(value = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes v WHERE v.book_id=id)"))
  Long votesCount;

...
}
```